# building tailwindcss with Vue3 install for production

Tags: npm, build, production, tailwind-css, vuejs3

I am quite unfamiliar with npm, (I develop in python) and most of the time I just do what the tutorial says. But now I am stuck. I tried Tailwindcss in combination wit 'Vue 3' and followed the install steps from the website:[website tailwind+Vue 3](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/vue-3-vite)

```
npm init @vitejs/app my-project
cd my-project
npm install
npm install -D tailwindcss@latest postcss@latest autoprefixer@latest
npx tailwindcss init -p
```

And after adding some HTML and running:

```
npm run dev
```

everything works fine in the browser.

But then Iwant to build it for using in production I use

```
npm run build
```

and after some processing my dist folder is filled with an index.html and assets.

And here starts my problem. I was expecting that I could copy these files to my server and that it should serve my site. But All I see is a blank page.

I can't find the answer anywhere or others with same problems so I think its something stupid I just don't know. But what is it?

Hope someone can help me...

Comment: what does the console say? any errors?

Comment: Thanks Keith, there were all 404 errors. no .js or .css was loaded. I changed it in the dist folder. Now it works. seems that the URLs are absolute. How should I change that during  build? I guess somewhere in a config.. Any suggestions..

Comment: How does your backend structure look like and what' the backend tech?

Comment: I am using the default Tailwind Vue3 install with default postcss.config.js, tailwind.confif.js and vite.config.js

Answer (score 0):

Try this, maybe something will work
https://dev.to/vonagedev/using-tailwind-css-with-vue-js-b1b

Webpack (and Vue-loader which is a Webpack loader for Vue.js components) can be configured to use PostCSS which is a Webpack loader for CSS.

It will look for the configuration inside a postcss.config.js file and can build the app with CSS from packages you add.
And, configure it using this code.

// postcss.config.js

```
const autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer');
const tailwindcss = require('tailwindcss');

module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    tailwindcss,
    autoprefixer,
  ],
};
```

The demo app is also generated without any CSS assets. Instead, it uses CSS inside the components (which is fine). To include Tailwind CSS, create a CSS asset using your editor or the commands below.

```
# mkdir -p for making parents they don't exist

mkdir -p src/assets/styles/
touch src/assets/styles/index.css
```

Now add this code, which adds the various packages of the Tailwind CSS library.

/* src/assets/styles/index.css */

````
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```
````